# Can Quantum Heisenburg Spin Model be regarded as a random walk?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin, probability

Can Quantum Heisenburg Spin Model be regarded as a random walk ?

We know that the 1D classical Ising Model can be regarded as a 1D random walk. For example, in the simplest case of the 1D Ising model, each spin is denoted as $S_{i}$. If we assume no interaction among spins, then the model can be considered a 1D binomial random walk, and the distribution of $S_{1} + S_{2} + ... + S_{n}$ can be seen as a 1D binomial coefficient.

For the 1D Quantum Heisenburg Spin Model:

$\displaystyle {\hat H}=-J\sum _{{j=1}}^{{N}}\sigma _{j}\sigma _{{j+1}}-h\sum _{{j=1}}^{{N}}\sigma _{j}$

Can it be regarded as a random walk? Can we also consider the distribution of $\sigma_{1} + \sigma_{2} + ... + \sigma_{n}$?

Answer (score 3):

For the **quantum** Heisenberg model, probably not. A quantum chain can be mapped on a *2-dimensional* classical system, so there exist representations in terms of suitable gas of two-dimensional loops, but not (as far as I can tell) as a *random walk*. (One relevant early reference is [this paper by Aizenman and Nachtergaele](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02108805).)

For the **classical** Heisenberg model, the situation is somewhat better. You cannot interpret it as  a random walk, in the usual sense of the term, but you *can* reinterpret the spin chain as a polymer chain in $\mathbb{R}^3$: in this case, all bonds in the polymer chain are of length $1$, the direction of the $k$th bond is given by $\sigma_k$ and the position of the $m$th monomer is given by
$$
X_m = \sigma_1 + \dots + \sigma_m.
$$
The **energy** associated to a particular configuration of the polymer chain $X_0=0, X_1, \dots, X_n$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{H}(X_0,\dots,X_n) = -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (X_i-X_{i-1})\cdot(X_{i+1}-X_i) = -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sigma_i\cdot \sigma_{i+1}.
$$
Note that this is a rather reasonable form for the energy, as it penalizes configurations in which the directions of successive bonds strongly differ and thus models a form of *rigidity* of the chain. In this sense, this model is similar to (a discrete version of) the [wormlike chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worm-like_chain).

Finally, in a case in which an external force $F$ acts on the free end ($X_n$) of the polymer (the other end, $X_0$, being kept pinned at the origin), one needs to add to the energy a term of the form
$$
F\cdot X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n F\cdot \sigma_i,
$$
which has exactly the same form as the magnetic field term in your spin chain.

**Remark**: Note that such a polymer model is *not* a random walk. In the standard terminology, the latter are supposed to have independent increments. Here the increments are not independent, but you still get a (rather simple) *Markov chain*. This is not an accident: any one-dimensional classical spin system is equivalent to a suitable Markov chain (although the latter usually does not have an independent interpretation as in this case).

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! Do you mean 1D quantum Heisenberg model can be mapped to 2D random walk ? @Yvan Velenik ?

Comment: No, it can be related to a two-dimensional system of loops. See, for instance, the paper I link to in my answer.